# uCommerce Installation Error for Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, sql, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

Using Umbraco version 7.1.4 assembly: 1.0.5261.28127

Download install package from ucommerce.net - uCommerce-for-Umbraco7-6.6.2.15058.zip

Attempted to install multiple times. First (10+) times that database was on Azure. The install doesn't "error" out, but I would suspect that I would have more database tables created in the database that I have:

[image]

The installation created an icon in the backoffice, `uCommerce`. However, when I click on it, I receive this error:

```
Server error: Contact administrator, see log for full details.
Failed to retrieve data for application tree uCommerce
```

In my log file:

```
ERROR NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute query: select user0_.UserId as UserId100_, user0_.ExternalId as ExternalId100_ from uCommerce_User user0_ where user0_.ExternalId=@p0

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'uCommerce_User'.
```

I found this link, [Invalid object name 'uCommerce_User'](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce/ucommerce-support/59745-BUG-SQL-Table-uCommerce_user-is-missing), which suggested to bring the `database` off of `Azure`.

I duplicated the `database` from `Azure` to my `local`, and changed the `connection string`. I browsed to the local instance to make sure that the `connection string` was working. Attempted to re-install another (10+) times, and still receive the same error when clicking on the `uCommerce` icon in the `Umbraco backoffice`.

It's obvious that I do not have `uCommerce_User` table created, as all the tables that were created from the installation are in the image above. I attempted to run all `128 sql` files from the installation folder in the package, but after the 4th script I began to receive `constrant` errors.

I have full rights to create tables, and do not know why it is erroring out. Anyone else have/had this issue?

Apprec -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all `constraints` from the Azure db regarding uCommerce tables, then deleted the uCommerce tables, and THEN re-ran all 130 sql scripts, and it installed OK. Now the uCommerce section in Umbraco is loading.